# How to get item index from ComboBox?

Tags: javafx, combobox

I have `ObservableList<Fruits> fruits`. Each fruit object has name and value parameters. Objects are: {"apples", 22}, {"oranges", 3} and {"pears", 5}. I added those items to `ComboBox`:

```
fruitComboBox.setItems(fruits);
```

How can I get item index from this `ComboBox` based on object's name? For example get index of "oranges" object?

I need to get index of item, so that I can use:

```
fruitComboBox.getSelectionModel.select(index);
```

full code will look like:

```
fruitComboBox.setItems(fruits);

fruitFactory = lv -> new ListCell<Fruits>){
     @Override
     protected void updateItem(Fruits fruit, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(fruit, empty);
        setText(empty ? "" : fruit.getName + ": " + fruit.getValue);
     }
};

fruitComboBox.setCellFactory(fruitFactory);
fruitComboBox.setButtonCell(fruitFactory.call(null));
```

For different people I need to select by default different fruits. I tried using:

```
fruitComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(orangeObject);
```

But it showed not formatted object in `ButtonCell`, also it didn't have any selection in open `ComboBox`. Using index gave perfect results:

```
fruitComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(2);
```

The only problem is, I don't know how I can get index of item in the `ComboBox` based on one of its parameters.

Comment: Iterate through the list and find the one that matches?

Comment: please clarify what exactly your requirement is - best read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly

Comment: So why do you specifically need the index? Why not just get the matching `Fruit` and select it directly?

Comment: What is `orangeObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
for (Fruit fruit : fruitComboBox.getItems()) {
    if ("oranges".equals(fruit.getName())) {
        fruitComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(fruit);
        break ;
    }
}
```

or, if you prefer a stream-based solution

```
fruitComboBox.getItems().stream()
    .filter(fruit -> "oranges".equals(fruit.getName()))
    .findAny()
    .ifPresent(fruitComboBox.getSelectionModel()::select);
```

Comment: in the mood for spoon feeding, aren't you <g>

Comment: @kleopatra Guilty as charged.

Comment: thanks, first example worked perfectly. I just can't understand why if I tried using `fruitComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(orangeObject);` (which is stored in `ComboBox`) it didn't work?

Comment: @Alyona Without knowing what `orangeObject` is, there's no possible way to answer that.

Comment: Basically, all objects are retrieved from database. Each object has name, value and id. Each user has favorite object. For example user has as favorite object link to orange object from fruits table. I was retrieving all objects from fruits table into `ComboBox` and then trying to do something like `fruitComboBox.getSelectionModel.select(CurrentUser.getFavoriteFruit())`. But as a result I got a raw object in `ButtonCell`.

Answer (score 1):

well to simply get the index of selected item in a combobox you can use .getselectedindex() method of combobox

Comment: however unclear the question is, there is no mention of selection - is there ;)

Comment: if not using a selection the we can also iterate through the list and for case match we can get that index

Comment: true, we can do lots of stuff :) please show what exactly you mean (assuming the requirement the item is the name/value pair mentioned by the OP and we want to find the index of the pair with a given name)